# How to connect to oracle database in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have Spark 3.1.2 and Scala 2.12.8. I want to connect to oracle Database and read a table then show it, using this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object readTable extends App{

   val spark = SparkSession
           .builder
           .master("local[*]")
           .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
           .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
           .getOrCreate()

   val jdbcDF = spark.read
           .format("jdbc") 
           .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521:orcldb")
           .option("dbtable", "orcl.brnc_grp")
           .option("user", "orcl")
           .option("password", "xxxxxxx")
           .load()

jdbcDF.show()

}
```

When I run the code, I receive this error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver**

Would you please guide me how to solve this problem?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download oracle JDBC jar from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-drivers-12c-downloads.html) and place this JAR in $SPARK_HOME/jars folder.